# Android Callback Error

Tags: java, android, interface, callback

I want to make a callback function in the `ShipInfoManager` to inform the `MainActivity` to do some action.

If I put `onEvent()` into `Runnable`, it runs. 
However If I put it like this, it shows an error.

Is there any way to fire the callback after loading data?
Or, is there any way to do the callback like Android's API's `LocatioManger`'s `requestLocationUpdates`, giving a callback when the data/variables is changed?

Thank you for any replies!

**MyCallback Interface**:

```
interface MyCallback {
    void callbackCall();
}
```

**ShipInfoManager class**:

```
public class ShipInfoManager {

    Context mContext;

    public ShipInfoManager(Context _mContext) {
        this.mContext = _mContext;

        reloadData();
        startTimer();
    }

    MyCallback callback;

    void onEvent() {
        callback.callbackCall();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
             /* RUN EVERY MIN */
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            reloadData();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        // TEMP SUSPEND FROM PREVENTING RELOAD //
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000);

    }

    /* JSON handling and extraction */
    private void reloadData() {
        //Do sth to reload the data

        //After reload, I want to fire the callback
        onEvent();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't any listeners to your callback and you're not checking for this.

You should replace your `ShipInfoManager` with this:

```
public class ShipInfoManager {
    public interface MyCallback {
        void callbackCall();
    }

    public void setCustomEventListener(MyCallback eventListener) {
       callback = eventListener;
    }

    Context mContext;

    public ShipInfoManager(Context _mContext)  {
        this.mContext = _mContext;

        reloadData();
        startTimer();
    }

    MyCallback callback;

    void onEvent() {
        // Check if we have listeners 
        if (callback != null)
            callback.callbackCall();
    }

    private void startTimer() {
         /* RUN EVERY MIN */
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        Timer timer = new Timer();
        TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            reloadData();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        };
        // TEMP SUSPEND FROM PREVENTING RELOAD //
        timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 5000);

    }

    /* JSON handling and extraction */
    private void reloadData() {
        //Do sth to reload the data

        //After reload, I want to fire the callback
        onEvent();

    }
}
```

Inside your `Activity` or `Fragment` you should have something like:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ShipInfoManager.MyCallback {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        ShipInfoManager s = new ShipInfoManager(this);
        s.setCustomEventListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void callbackCall() {

    }
}
```

Comment: I modified the code like yours (including that in Activity), but callBack is still null. So how can I make a listener in the mainActivity?

Comment: @user3297749 see my update, I have added `setCustomEventListener(MyCallback eventListener)` to the `ShipInfoManager` class and showed how to hook this up inside your `Activity`

Answer (score 0):

I changed my MainActivity like this. It works now.
Thank you for your suggestion and reply!!!!!

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {


ShipInfoManager mShipInfo;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mShipInfo = new ShipInfoManager(this);


    Log.i("Show Ship List Size", String.valueOf(mShipInfo.get_shipsList().size()));
    Log.i("Show Ship - 6", String.valueOf(mShipInfo.getShip(6).getShip_name()));



    mShipInfo.callback = new ShipInfoManager.MyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void callbackCall() {
            Log.i("Call Back", "it is called");
        }
    };




}
```